# Ant cannot find the path specified

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, ant, jboss

I'm trying to run a .bat file in an Ant script, which is as follows:

```
<property name="winPath" value="C:\jboss-root\jboss-fuse-6.1.0.redhat-379\bin"/>
<property name="cmdPath" value="C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" />
<echo message="Windows: ${winPath} | ${cmdPath}" />       
<exec dir="${winPath}" executable="${cmdPath}">
    <arg value="/c"/><arg value="fuse.bat"/><arg value="-p"/> 
</exec>
```

The output of this script is as follows:

```
[echo] Executing JBoss Fuse Start Script...
[echo] Windows: C:\jboss-root\jboss-fuse-6.1.0.redhat-379\bin | C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
[exec] The system cannot find the path specified.
[exec] Result: 3
```

The file does exist, and by running the command manually in cmd it executes the script fine.

```
C:\jboss-root\jboss-fuse-6.1.0.redhat-379\bin>C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c fuse.bat -p
Please wait while JBoss Fuse is loading...
```

I've tried replacing \ for /, but no change. The Ant documentation says to either place the filepaths in PATH, or use absolute filepaths. I am not able to modify the PATH files, though.

Comment: I was having the same situation I have then braked the commands in two exec first to go to the dir that is cd command than you can ran the command you want to exec

Comment: run ant with -debug flags.  That will dump actual commands.

Comment: Try by specifiying `executable="cmd"` and then for locating bat file with arg value use `<arg value="${cmdPath}\fuse.bat"/>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was caused due to the fact that Ant did not have the correct JAVA_HOME, and was supplying an invalid location to fuse.bat - the error in the log is actually fuse.bat reporting that it can't find java.exe.